# How can I preserve the variable type in a tibble after applying map or modify

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
 > impute_sample <- function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x),
    sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = sum(is.na(x)), replace = T),
    x
  )
}
> dd <- tibble(date=as.Date(c("2010-2-1",NA,"2020-3-2")),
               value = c(1,NA,2),
               grp = c("df","s",NA))
> dd
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  date       value grp  
  <date>     <dbl> <chr>
1 2010-02-01     1 df   
2 NA            NA s    
3 2020-03-02     2 NA   
> dd%>%modify(impute_sample)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   date value grp  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 14641     1 df   
2 18323     1 s    
3 18323     2 s    
> dd%>%map_df(impute_sample)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   date value grp  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 14641     1 df   
2 18323     2 s    
3 18323     2 df
```

The other types can be preserved well, but the date is transformed to dbl type; How can I still preserve the date type after sample imputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with the `impute_sample()` function's reliance on `ifelse` which is rather notorious for producing unpredictable output given that it will happily convert data types quietly without any explicit go-ahead from the user. The routine works as expected if we simply replace `ifelse` with `dplyr::if_else` which.  As the help file states:

> `Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.`

You can see the difference this makes in the reprex below.

```r
# load required libraries
library(tidyverse)

# define original function (base::ifelse)
impute_sample <- function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x),
         sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = sum(is.na(x)), replace = T),
         x)
}

# define type-consistent version of function (dplyr::if_else)
impute_sample_consistent <- function(x) {
  if_else(is.na(x),
         sample(x[!is.na(x)], size = sum(is.na(x)), replace = T),
         x)
}

# define data
dd <- tibble(
  date = as.Date(c("2010-2-1", NA, "2020-3-2")),
  value = c(1, NA, 2),
  grp = c("df", "s", NA)
)

# apply original version using purrr::modify
dd %>% modify(impute_sample)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    date value grp  
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 14641     1 df   
#> 2 18323     1 s    
#> 3 18323     2 df

# apply type-consistent version using purrr::modify
dd %>% modify(impute_sample_consistent)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   date       value grp  
#>   <date>     <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 2010-02-01     1 df   
#> 2 2020-03-02     1 s    
#> 3 2020-03-02     2 s
```

Lastly, even though you did not explicitly ask about this, it may be worth emphasizing something fundamental about `purrr::modify` as it tends to trip people up in practice.  The help file states:

> `...the modify() family always returns the same type as the input object.`

When given an object as input, there is no reason to expect `purrr::modify` to preserve the types of the individual elements in the input, only of the input itself.  In other words, if you pass a data frame of type `x` (e.g. `tibble`, `data.table`, etc) as input to `purrr::modify`, it will produce a data frame of type `x` as output.  However, it is totally possible (and consistent with `purrr::modify`'s definition) for the types of the individual columns in that data frame to be changed.  To illustrate, take your `dd` tibble as an example:

```r
# it is possible to use modify to convert column types
dd %>% modify(type.convert)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   date       value grp  
#>   <fct>      <int> <fct>
#> 1 2010-02-01     1 df   
#> 2 <NA>          NA s    
#> 3 2020-03-02     2 <NA>

# but the class of the input and output to modify remains the same
class(dd)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(dd %>% modify(type.convert))
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```